# Is it semantically correct to use "specifically with an emphasis on..." in the following sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it semantically correct to use "specifically with an emphasis on..." in the following sentence? Could there be confusion as to whether "emphasis" refers to "Rowling" or "I"?

> Considering Rowling's description of Ilvermorny, specifically with an emphasis on indigenous tradition, I will use  Robert James Muckle's research on indigenous people's of North America to see how Rowling...

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Please note proofreading requests are off-topic here. Please tell why you think this usage may not be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that phrase is grammatically valid, although it is a bit wordy and keyword.  I might rephrase it by writing "specifically her emphasis on..." instead of "specifically with an emphasis on..." . I might also split it into multiple shorter sentences, but I wouldn't want to do this without seeing the full sentence, and preferably nthe full paragraph from which it comes.

By the way, that should be "indigenous **peoples** of North America" not "indigenous people's of North America" because this is a plural (more than one people) not a possessive or genitive (something belonging to or associated with a people {Example, "The people's rights"}). It is an increasingly commo9n error to use 's to form a plural, but it is still an error. 's is never used to forma plural, while it is the regulsr way to form a genitive.  Perhaps eventually this will be accepted as standard English, but it hasn't been as yet.

Comment: And what if "emphasis" refers to "I", not "Rowling"? Will it still be correct?

Comment: @BeatsMe  No not at all. That would require significant rephraing of the sentence, and should probably abe a separate but linked question.